# Why regular expression doesn't match input with sed command

Tags: sed, regular-expression, ps

I'd like to cut extra spaces from "ps aux" output and replace them with one space. What I do is:

```
ps axu | sed 's/[ ]+/ /g'
```

But output seems to be unchanged, I still get too much spaces between tokens.

```
username    4876 ... <the rest of columns ommitted>
```

Why this regular expression doesn't match empty space between username and pid?

Comment: BRE is not ERE ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `sed` uses basic regular expressions (BRE), and `+` isn't part of them. Use `s/  */ /` (two spaces in the pattern part), or `-E` for extended regular expressions in GNU or BSD `sed`: `sed -E 's/ +/ /g'`

Comment: Or use `\{1,\}`, the standard BRE equivalent of ERE `+`.